# mistake using cypher collection (while creating a chain of nodes)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I made a query that creates a chain of nodes by attaching to C node-s an ordered collection of p-nodes (if they all have the same id, in our case '-670'). There is no problem in creating an ordered collection of p-nodes, but i've got a mistake in line `CREATE(c)<-[:RELATED_TO]-(Ps[0])` full query

```
MATCH (c:C{id: -670}), (p:P{id:-670})
WHERE not(p-[:RELATED_TO]->())
WITH p, c 
ORDER BY p.t_start
with collect(p) as Ps, c

//This create doesn't work
CREATE (c)<-[:RELATED_TO]-(Ps[0])

//This create works fine
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, length(Ps)-2) |
FOREACH(pay1 in [Ps[i]] |
FOREACH(pay2 in [Ps[i+1]] |
CREATE UNIQUE (pay1)<-[:RELATED_TO]-(pay2))))

RETURN Ps, c
```

Mistake: "Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, whitespace or ')' (line 6)"

This is first time i'm using collection in cypher, and i really don't know what is wrong with it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
MATCH (c:C{id: -670}), (p:P{id:-670})
WHERE not(p-[:RELATED_TO]->())
WITH collect(p) AS ps, c 
ORDER BY p.t_start
WITH p[0] AS p0, c
CREATE (c)<-[:RELATED_TO]-(p0)
```

You might be able to get away with:

```
WITH collect(p)[0] AS p0, c
```

Though I've not tried that

Comment: WHERE not(p-[:RELATED_TO]->())
WITH p, c 
ORDER BY p.t_start
with collect(p) as ps, c WITH ps[0] as p0, ps, c worked in my case. Thanks